# Node.js Socket.io mysql returning duplicates

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm having this issue with socket.io. Whenever the user clicks the link it goes to mysql, pulls data and passes it back to the client side. I find that when I click the link n times I get n duplicates. If I click the link 3 times the returned arrays are duplicated three times. Is this an issue with my client side, server side, or is the approach itself all wrong?

client Side:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#view_conv", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = $("#view_conv").data('id');
      socket.emit("viewing_conv_get_messages", data, uname);
      $("#close_observ_window").show();
      socket.on("show_message", function(htmldata){
          $("#obvs_content").append(htmldata);
      });
  });
  $("#close_observ_window").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#obvs_content").empty();
  });
```

Server side:

```
client.query("SELECT id FROM conversations WHERE user_one = ? AND user_two = ? AND active = ?", [name_one, name_two, 1],
               function selectCb(err, results){
                  if(err){ throw err; }
                    if(results.length > 0){
                      var convId = "";
                      var str = "";
                      for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                        convId = str + results[i].id;
                      }
                    client.query("SELECT `message`,`sender` FROM chat_messages WHERE conv_id = ? ORDER BY(id) DESC", convId,
                       function selectCb(err, res){
                          if(err){ throw err; }
                          else {
                            if(res.length > 0){
                            for(var j=0; j<res.length; j++){
                              var string_m = '';
                              var string_send = '';
                              var message = string_m + res[j].message;
                              var sender = string_send + res[j].sender;
                                  content = "<b>" + sender + "</b> : " + message + " <br>";
                                 users[users[users.indexOf(admin)]].emit("show_message", content);
                                 console.log(j);
                            }
                          }
                           // recurse_messages(res, admin, 0);
                        }

                       });
                    }
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your socket.on outside the click function.

With you current code each time you click **#view_conv** a listener is added. So when you click 3 times in effect there would be 3 listeners for **show_message** event.

Try modifying code like this

client Side:

```
$(document).on("click", "#view_conv", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#view_conv").data('id');
    socket.emit("viewing_conv_get_messages", data, uname);
    $("#close_observ_window").show();
});

socket.on("show_message", function(htmldata){
  $("#obvs_content").append(htmldata);
});

$("#close_observ_window").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$("#obvs_content").empty();
});
```

You should always try to write listeners independently (ie., outside all functions)

Comment: :) glad i could help